# Fatal error when trying to format output using date_diff()

Tags: php, date, datediff

I'm using PHP 5.3.6 and when I try to run the code bellow I get the following error: "
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in ...".

```
function diferenta_date($data_inceput, $data_sfarsit){
    $interval = date_diff(date_create($data_inceput), date_create($data_sfarsit));
    $output = $interval->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s");

    $return_output = array();
    array_walk(explode(',', $output), function($val, $key) use(&$return_output) {
                $v = explode(':', $val);
                $return_output[$v[0]] = $v[1];
            });

    return $return_output;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to learn how to [READ and debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the error message. $interval is not a valid object

Comment: Seems like date_diff is not returning you an object, but I can not guess why, sorry.

Comment: `date_diff()` probably returned `false` because it failed, probably because one (or both) of the `date_create()` calls failed. What are the values of `$data_inceput` and `$data_sfarsit`?

Comment: What type of `$data_inceput`, `$data_sfarsit` vars?

Comment: @Bora, string values, like '2013-07-28'.

Comment: I didnt get any error with string params like '2013-07-28'. PHP 5.3.13

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return values.  [The documentation says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) date_diff() returns:

> The DateInterval object representing the difference between the two dates or **FALSE on failure**.

date_diff() is failing and you are trying to use FALSE as an object.